# Can the value and text properties of a dropdown list be used independently?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

Can these two properties of a dropdown list in ASP.NET be used independently?

I wanted to retrieve a `null` value when the user selects some text; I couldn't as it retrieves the `Text` property whenever the `Value` is `null`. Eg:

```
l1 = new ListItem("Cat", null);
Console.WriteLine(l1.Value);
```

The output is

> Cat

In another situation, when both the properties have different strings, I get the string in the `Value` property when I use the `Text` property. Eg:

```
l2 = new ListItem("Cat", "Mouse");
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.Items.Add(li);
ddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
Console.WriteLine(ddl.SelectedValue);
Console.WriteLine(ddl.Text);
```

The output is

> Mouse
>   Mouse

Comment: That sounds strange. Can you post a *small* working example of the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: Point 1 is true - Text will be used if value is null, 
Point 2 sounds wrong -  Text will be used if Text and Value are populated and you access Text

Comment: @Heinzi: is it clear now?  @longhairedsi: yeah its strange but i get the Value property when i access both Text and Value...

Comment: Yes, it's clear now, thanks. The problem is that you are accessing the `Text` property of the DropDownList rather than the `Text` property of the ListItem. I've added a detailed explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observation is correct. Contrary to what intuition tells us, `ListControl.Text` (and, thus, `DropDownList.Text`) does *not* return the `Text` property of the currently selected `ListItem`. Here's an excerpt from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.text.aspx):

> **ListControl.Text Property**
>
> Gets or sets the SelectedValue property of the ListControl control.
>
> [...]
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The Text property gets and sets the same value that the SelectedValue property does.

To get the `Text` property of the selected `ListItem`, use `SelectedItem` to retrieve the currently selected list item and then access the `Text` property.

So, the behavior you are seeing is by design. Why did the .NET developers specify `ListControl.Text` in such an unintuitive way? I have no idea. Maybe it was necessary to support the `ITextControl` interface...

Comment: Yeah got it now, I can access the `Text` property by first retrieving the `SelectedItem`. Thanks. Damn right its counter-intuitive.

Comment: I've added a question about the reason for this design decision: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232610. Maybe someone else knows more about this...

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value to some sentinel value like an empty string or some crazy string "**JANDKJASD_**" and handle it accordingly.

Comment: A sentinel would solve the first problem. What about the second? Plus, using an empty string again causes the Value property to be same as the Text property.