# ASP.NET: Why does ListControl.Text return the *value* of the selected ListItem rather than the *text*?

Tags: asp.net, listcontrol

List controls deriving from `ListControl`, such as `DropDownList`, `ListBox` or `RadioButtonList`, are populated by a list of `ListItem`s. A `ListItem` has a `Value` and a `Text` property.

`ListControl` offers the following methods to access the currently selected item:

- `ListControl.SelectedItem` returns the currently selected `ListItem`,
- `ListControl.SelectedValue` returns the `Value` property of the currently selected `ListItem`.

Now, the interesting thing is:

- `ListControl.Text` returns exactly the same value as `ListControl.SelectedValue`. It does *not* return `SelectedItem.Text`, as one might expect.

This is [by design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.text.aspx):

> **ListControl.Text Property**
>
> Gets or sets the SelectedValue property of the ListControl control.
>
> [...]
>
> **Remarks**
>
> The Text property gets and sets the same value that the SelectedValue property does.

This seems counter-intuitive and [confuses people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232093). My question is: Why was it done this way? I can imagine that providing a `Text` property is necessary for implementing the `ITextControl` interface, but why on earth would you choose to have it return the `Value` of the ListItem rather than the `Text`?

Answer (score 1):

If the code used to process an ASPX page defines all controls using the `ITextControl` interface, the `Text` property is the only property available.  When processing a `ListControl`, most of the business logic I write cares about the value of the selected item, not the text.  Thus, in my opinion, the current behavior is the desired behavior, even if it is not necessarily the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I checked that out before using .NET Reflector.  If ListItem.Text is null, it returns ListItem.Value instead; if that is null, it returns an empty string.  It works in vice versa for ListItem.Value too.  So it's not the ListControl doing this, it's selected item itself.

HTH.