# Why would DropDownList.Text is return 0 when it is clearly an empty string?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a drop down list that I am binding to a record that clearly sets value=0, text=''

the dropdownlist looks fine, i do not see any text in the control BUT when i try to validate in the code behind it says the dropdownlist.text = 0

i do not know why the control shows no text on the form but holds a value in its .text property, it doesn't make any sense. can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Post the relevant code please.

Comment: [This has kind of been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232093/can-the-value-and-text-properties-of-a-dropdown-list-be-used-independently)

Comment: `text=''` Why are you using single quotes to set a [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.string.aspx) value ? This is not Transact-SQL.

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk I think the OP is referring to markup attributes there, where the type of quote doesn't matter (as long as they match).

Comment: @Pow-Ian similar question, had i worded my search differently for the 20th time i may have stumbled upon it. PS. thanks for the direction. :)

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk  its pseudo code. i was just trying to get my point across the code didnt matter, it was the theory i was interested in.

Comment: @nmat see comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue I was having by inserting a null value along with the text of '' and now the dropdownlist.text is = '' intead of 0.